# Mount a .vdi in Windows 7 as a hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vdi

On my Windows 7 machine (host), I have a virtual machine (VirtualBox) running Ubuntu 10.10 - inside the .vdi, I have some large files that I would like to extract - one of them being a standalone .iso file.

I want to mount Ubuntu's .VDI as a hard drive in my host system, Windows 7.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are making things much more complicated than it should be.

If you want to bring files over to your host system, the easiest way is to [create shared folders](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders) between the host and guest. You can then transfer the file to the host OS and extract it there.

If you *must* mount this disk as a hard drive, you can [convert it to VMDK](http://www.xgrr.de/wordpress/2008/02/25/convert-virtualbox-vdi-to-vmware-vmdk) and [mount it](http://4sysops.com/archives/free-vmware-diskmount-gui-mount-vmdk-files/) that way.